# Are there any simulators around to simulate ADS-B data (TIS-B & FIS-B)?

Tags: ads-b, flight-simulator

I am trying to find a simulator like the Spirent GPS Simulators. Are there any Simulators out there which can simulate and generate random traffic and weather information for TIS-B & FIS-B testing?

I have an ADS-B 978 UAT receiver hooked up to an antenna which receives signals mostly from 1 tower. I would like to hook up a simulator to the UAT receiver which can simulate the ADS-B data block (customized). I tried searching via Git and many other places couldn't find one.

Has anybody came across any such a thing? Objective - TIS-B to generate random traffic, FIS-B to generate necessary weather.

Comment: How do you search with `git`?

Comment: @Steve https://github.com/git and use the search box in the upper right of the page. I tried "ads-b" and "ads b" and found no repositories with those terms in the their title.

Comment: most of the software I have seen is to decode ADS-B data. Here's the searches I get at github for "ads-b" https://github.com/search?p=2&q=ads-b&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: While this can probably be done with a SDR, I would be very weary of doing it outside of a lab environment. The problem is that you can't contain the signal and while it probably won't travel far, a low flying aircraft directly overhead may pick up your simulated signals. You may want to look into something you can hook directly into the antenna port so you aren't actually broadcasting bad data, but I'm guessing if you have that kind of budget you wouldn't be looking for open source software...

Comment: @selectstriker2 Ah, GitHub. That's a service. `git` is the version control system.

Comment: @RonBeyer I will not be broadcasting the data. So far whatever I searched returned all decoders of real time data. My Intention is to generate the ADS-B data just like a ground station. (mimic it) in closed and wired method. In that way I would be able to generate a random traffic or weather with my own customization.

Comment: I am developing a display software system which I would like to test it is capable of all combination of weather and traffic. Right now, I am at the mercy of the real broadcast.

Answer (score 1):

[Aeroflex IFR-6000](https://www.testequipmentconnection.com/66511/Aeroflex_IFR_6000.php)

From the manufacturer's website:

> The Aeroflex IFR 6000 is a compact, lightweight and weatherproof unit designed for testing transponder modes A/C/S, TCAS I and II as well as DME. Includes antenna shield and hard transit case. The IFR 6000 features an extremely easy to use interface where every parameter the user commonly needs to view is displayed on screen.
>
> Dedicated Mode keys for XPDR, DME and TCAS allow quick selection of the operational mode. The application dependent softkeys and data select/slew keys provide an intuitive man machine interface. DME mode is provided with dedicated keys for frequency/channel selection and RF level control.
>
> For frequently varied parameters in DME and TCAS modes, such as Range and Rate, dedicated keys are provided. Each operational mode has one main user screen. The operational modes are: XPDR (Sub-Modes: ADS-B MON, ADS-B GEN & GICB) DME TCAS 1, 2 (Sub-Modes: TIS) Most tests can be completed without leaving the main user screens. This simplifies the line technician's testing task.

However, it is subject to stringent export restrictions. If you are outside of the US, it is not available to you.